# Perform index match with multiple calculated conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried the formulas below for an index match with if statement but not getting a correct answer. Where I am making mistake?

```
=IF(INDEX(AE$3:AE$2000,MATCH(MIN(ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3)),ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3),0)),AD$3:AD$2000=$AN3)

=IF(AD$3:AD$2000=$AN3,INDEX(AE$3:AE$2000,MATCH(MIN(ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3)),ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3),0)),IF(AD$3:AD$2000=$BN3,INDEX(AE$3:AE$2000,MATCH(MIN(ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3)),ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3),0)),"")) 

=--(AD$3:AD$2000=$AN3)INDEX(AE$3:AE$2000,MATCH(MIN(ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3)),ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3),0)) 

=INDEX(AE$3:AE$2000,MATCH(MIN(ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3)),ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3),IF(AD$3:AD$2000=$AN3),0))

=INDEX(AE$3:AE$2000,MATCH(SMALL(IF(AD$3:AD$2000=$AN3,ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3)),1),IF(AD$3:AD$2000=$AN3,ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3),0))
```

Comment: It may be easier if you show some data and state exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Scott.......I am trying to find out nearest value or number from given table. For that simply I can use =INDEX(AE$3:AE$2000,MATCH(MIN(ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3)),ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3),0)) 
( I am posting above code in "Add Comment", therefore could not understand how to post in { } )
But there are bunch of tables in same column. So the nearest value will be more than one, therefore need to use IF function. So if $AN3 ( say "John") has table in column AD$3:AD$2000. First find or search "John" in AD column and from that table index match nearest value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this array¹ formula.

```
=INDEX(AE$3:AE$2000, AGGREGATE(15,  6, ROW($1:$1998)/((MIN(ABS(TRANSPOSE(AE$3:AE$2000)-$AS3))=ABS(AE$3:AE$2000-$AS3))*(AD$3:AD$2000=$AN3)), 1))
```

[image: AS3]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: Jeeped.....the above your code working though, but when I drag down, I got error #NUM in between some cells.

Comment: You need to go through the formula and add/remove the **$** symbol so that the rows are locked where you want them locked (i.e. absolute reference) and unlocked (i.e. relative reference) where you want them to progress to new rows where they should progress.